# Entity is not saved to database via WebApi call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to insert an item using Entity Framework via a WebApi action. The context seems to show that the item has been saved, but when I check in the underlying database the item was not saved.

The HelpRequest parameter in PostHelpRequest is resolved correctly (it matches what I include in the PostMan body data)

Here is the action:

```
public class HelpRequestController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage PostHelpRequest(HelpRequest item)
    {
        var context = new MyDbContext();
        try
        {
            using (var newcontext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                newcontext.HelpRequests.Add(item);
                newcontext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<HelpRequest>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = 0 });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

My context:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<HelpRequest> HelpRequests { get; set; }

}
```

My generated model:

```
public partial class HelpRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Responded { get; set; }
}
```

I am testing this via PostMan and my body data is set to raw, json

```
{"Title":"Title1","Message":"Message1","CreateDate":"2017-02-05T10:03:35.258"}
```

The Id column in the database is set as primary and identity.

Edit:

I have found the issue, but not sure how to solve it.

When I step through the code and look at newcontext.Database.ConnectionString it is referencing a SQLExpress database - it seems it made one for the project.

However, when I open up the model and look at the connection string, it is referencing the correct server and database.

Why is the context being assigned the wrong connection string?

Edit: connection string and context constructor

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connname1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=mydatabase1;user id=andrewb;password=hahayeahright;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Constructor:

```
public MyDbContext()
{
    Database.Log = sql => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sql);
}
```

Final edit: The solution was that I need to set the constructor in my context with the name of the connection string I want to use. See Igor's answer.

Comment: Do you happen to have SQL statement logging enabled? What does the INSERT statement look like in the log?

Comment: Side note: Change `throw new Exception(ex.Message);` to `throw;` or remove the entire `catch` block. `throw;` will preserve the stack trace to the original Exception, your existing statement resets it which is bad for trying to figure out why an exception was thrown.

Comment: I agree, this is just getting it to work first, but I can confirm that no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: `but when I check in the underlying database the item was not saved` <= how are you checking? Where are you checking? Is this a localdb instance? If so are you sure you are looking at the same file that your code points to?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky do you mean profiler? I just ran it and submitted a request but the trace never showed anything related.

Comment: @Igor I check in the database which I am targeting in the entity connection string, table is empty

Comment: What database are you using? MsSql server? localdb? oracle? sql lite? something else?

Comment: SQL Server 2015

Comment: I kinda doubt it, MS never released a 2015 version....

Comment: Typo - 2016, version 13.0.15900.1

Comment: If profiler is not showing any trace that means data is going somewhere else. Check and double check the conn string. Check the conn string of Context while debugging. Make sure that the trace is pointing to the right db.

Comment: Good deal. Have you ran `Sql Profiler` at the same time your code is running so you can see the code executing the insert statement against your database and the server response?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Updated my question - conn string is being assigned to the wrong conn

Comment: Can you share the constructor of the context?also check connectionstrings section of web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `web.config` section `connectionStrings`. Ideally you create a unique name for your connection string and use that name in the constructor of your `DbContext`. Even easier is to pass that name through in the default constructor to the parameterized constructor of `DbContext`.

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("Name=bcard_portal")

    public DbSet<HelpRequest> HelpRequests { get; set; }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="bcard_portal" connectionString="data source=servername;initial catalog=mydatabase1;user id=andrewb;password=hahayeahright;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

Side note: If you are using EF6 and code first with `DbContext` then use a standard ADO.NET db connection string in your `web.config`, not the convoluted version that the (older) edmx designer makes use of.